# Script .sh para executar um programa em python de dentro do Cron

Tags: python, shell-script, cron

Bom dia. estou tendo um problema com um programa em python que eu fiz.
O que acontece é que quando eu executo meu programa pela linha de comando com este comando ele funciona normal :

```
python3 /home/linaro/programa/main.py > /home/linaro/log.txt &
```

dai eu fiz o seguinte programinha em .sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -C 'python3 /home/linaro/programa/main.py' > /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
   then
      // programa rodando
   else
      //echo "Iniciando o programa" > /home/linaro/log.txt
      python3 /home/linaro/programa/main.py > /home/linaro/log.txt
fi
```

quando executo por ele o programa também funciona mas quando incluo este comando no crontab desta forma:

```
* * * * * root /home/linaro/gerente.sh
```

o meu programa inicia a execução, entra na memoria e funciona alguns segundos e simplesmente para sem dar erro ou sem sair da memoria.

alguém poderia me auxiliar a gerar um arquivo que controle a execução do meu programa em python se o meu estiver errado ? ou teria alguma dica de como fazer isto funcionar ?

Comment: Não está suficientemente claro o problema, Se o programa para, como ele continua na memória?

Comment: o funcionamento dele , isto é as funções que ele deveria executar não são feitas. mas o processo ainda esta em memoria.

Comment: Se o processo está travando, deve ter alguma coisa errada no código que está fazendo ele parar..

Answer (score 1):

Já que aparentemente voce está no `Linux`, você poderia dispensar o seu `.sh` passando a responsabilidade de verificar se já existe outro processo em execução para o seu código `Python`, veja só:

```
import fcntl, sys

pid_file = '/var/run/script.py.pid'

fp = open( pid_file, 'w' )

try:
    fcntl.lockf( fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB )
    print('Em execucao!')
except IOError:
    print('Jah estou em execucao!')
    sys.exit(1)

# ....

print('Finalizado!')

sys.exit(0)
```

Que por sua vez criaria o arquivo de *lock* `/var/run/script.py.pid` para fazer o controle da instância única do processo.

O que permitiria uma configuração como essa em sua  `crontab`:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /home/linaro/programa/main.py > /home/linaro/log.txt
```

Referência: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems

Comment: vou tentar desta forma tbm obrigado

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o problema segue como ficou meu cod final

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -aux | grep -P '[p]ython3 /home/linaro/aifaces/main.py(?! -post)' > /dev/null
var1=$?

ps -aux | grep '[p]ython3 /home/linaro/aifaces/main.py -[p]ost' > /dev/null
var2=$?

if [ $var1 = $var2 ]
        then
                if [ "$var1" = 1 ]
                        then
                                # nao esta rodando, executa programa
                                python3 /home/linaro/aifaces/main.py > /home/linaro/log.txt
                        else
                                #esta rodando, envia keepalive
                                uuid=$(cat /etc/machine-id)
                                curl -s -w -X POST --data uuid=$uuid https://apiweb.com.br/keepalive
                fi
        else
                # so um processo ta rodando mata todos e restarta sistema
                kill $(ps aux | grep '[p]ython3 /home/linaro/aifaces/main.py' | awk '{print $2}')
fi
```